# How can I split a text file line by line into 2 text files by delimited column?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-manipulation

I've tried various combinations of the following:

```
awk -F" ||| " '{$0=$1}1' source_file.txt > column1.txt
awk -F" ||| " '{$0=$1}2' source_file.txt > column2.txt
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" ||| ";}{print $1}' source_file.txt > column1.txt
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" ||| ";}{print $2}' source_file.txt > column2.txt
```

Instead of the desired output, I either get the entire line (ex. `foo bar ||| baz`) or I get only the first word (ex. `foo`).

If you'd like to help, here is a sample text file:

**source_file.txt**

```
foo bar ||| baz
qux ||| quux
corge grault ||| garply waldo
fred |||
xyzzy ||| thud
```

**And here's the desired output:**

**column1.txt**

```
foo bar
qux
corge grault
fred
xyzzy
```

**column2.txt**

```
bar
quux
garply waldo

thud
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F' \\|\\|\\| ?' '{print $1 > "column1"; print $2 > "column2"}' file
```

or more generally

```
awk -F' \\|\\|\\| ?' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "column"i}' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you also get this error? `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > >>>  "column"i <<< }
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: No errors in my case, make sure you're using single quotes for the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
cat /tmp/a | tr -s '|' | cut -d'|' -f1 #for part 1

cat /tmp/a | tr -s '|' | cut -d'|' -f2 | sed -E "s/^[[:space:]]+//g" #for part 2
```

The `tr` flag squeezes delimiters together.